# QR factorization & Regularized Least Squares

Tags: optimization, least-squares, quadratic-programming, regularization

Given *regularized-least squares*

$$\min_x ||Ax - b||^2+ \lambda||x||^2  $$

How do you use QR decomposition to find a solution?

I understand that QR decomposition leads to $Rx = Q^Tb$, but how do you incorporate $\lambda||x||^2$?

Following the suggestions and solutions I have: 
$$
\begin{align}
(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b) + \lambda x^Tx &= x^T(A^TA+\lambda I)x - 2b^TAx+b^Tb \\
      (take \ derivative)   &= 2(A^TA+\lambda I)x - 2A^Tb = 0 \\
              &= (A^TA+\lambda I)x = A^Tb \\
              &= ((QR)^TQR + \lambda I)x = (QR)^Tb \\
              &= (R^TR + \lambda I)x = R^TQ^Tb\\
              &= x = (R^TR+ \lambda I)^{-1} R^TQ^Tb \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hint: rewrite the objective to $x^T C x + d^Tx + e$.

Comment: Can you hint what $e$, $C$, and $d$ are?

Comment: Write $||Ax-b||^2$ as $(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b)$, and $||x||$ as $x^T I x$.

Comment: Then would you get the express: $(QRx-b)^T(QRx-b) + \lambda x^TIx$and minimize that?

Comment: I've updated the question to show some of my work.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the objective is $(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b)+ \lambda x^T x = x^T (A^T A +\lambda I) x - 2 b^T Ax + b^Tb$. Taking the derivative yields $2(A^TA+\lambda I)x - 2 A^Tb = 0$, or $(A^TA+\lambda I)x = A^Tb$. Hence $x=(A^TA+\lambda I)^{-1}A^Tb$. The trick is now to take a QR decomposition of $A^TA+\lambda I$ (instead of just $A^TA$), so you can write $x=R^{-1}Q^TA^Tb$.

Comment: @LutzL thanks, I updated my answer.

Comment: Numerically, one wants to avoid computing $A^TA$ as that squares the condition number. Use $A=QR$ to reduce to $(R^TR+λI)x = y=R^TQ^Tb$ where now in the lower part $x_k=λ^{-1}y_k$ and only the upper part where $R^TR$ is non-trivial needs to be solved.

Comment: wouldn't the answer at the end be $x = (R^TR+\lambda I)^{-1}R^TQ^Tb $?

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how $\lambda$ disappears in the solution.

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: $\lambda$ is in the matrix of which the QR decomposition is taken